# Call function from Jupyter Notebook using argparse command line arguments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-line-arguments, argparse, jupyter-lab

I have a module that I normally run from the command line using argparse. However, I would like to call the main function from Jupyter Notebook (normally in Jupyter Lab) so that I can analyze the return object.

A simple example. Here is a simple python file called 'getinformation.py'. While there is only one argument here, my real life situation has many arguments.

```
import argparse

def get_info(args=None):
    args = parse_args(args)
    print(args.gi)
    return args.gi

def parse_args(pargs=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
        description=("Arg Parser from Jupyter please"),
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--gi",
        default=None,
        required=False,
        help="Test argument..",
    )


    return parser.parse_args(pargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    get_info()
```

This would run from the command line as:

```
getinformation.py --gi "test string"
```

How can I call get_info() using the command line arguments from Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Have  you tried the `%run` magic?  Or import the module, and call `get_info(['--gi','foobar')`.  That is, call `get_info` with a sys.argv like list of strings.

Comment: @hpaulj That did it, thanks. Appreciate the help.